# How do I set a MIME type before sending a file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, webserver

When sending scripts from my Node.js server to the browser, in Google Chrome, I get this warning:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/plain

I Google'd around, and found out that it's a server-side problem, namely, I think that I should set the correct MIME type to things, before sending them. Here's the HTTP server's handler:

```
var handler = function(req, res)
{
    url = convertURL(req.url); //I implemented "virtual directories", ignore this.

    if (okURL(url)) //If it isn't forbidden (e.g. forbidden/passwd.txt)
    {
        fs.readFile (url, function(err, data)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                res.writeHead(404);
                return res.end("File not found.");
            }

            //I think that I need something here.
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(data);
        });
    }
    else //The user is requesting an out-of-bounds file.
    {
        res.writeHead(403);
        return res.end("Forbidden.");
    }
}
```

Question: **How do I correct my server-side code to configure the MIME type correctly?**

(Note: I already found https://github.com/broofa/node-mime, but it only lets me determine the MIME type, not to "set" it.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I figured it out!

Thanks to @rdrey's [link](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) and [this node module](https://github.com/broofa/node-mime) I managed to correctly set the MIME type of the response, like this:

```
function handler(req, res) {
    var url = convertURL(req.url);

    if (okURL(url)) {
        fs.readFile(url, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(404);
                return res.end("File not found.");
            }

            res.setHeader("Content-Type", mime.lookup(url)); //Solution!
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(data);
        });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(403);
        return res.end("Forbidden.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Search google for the Content-Type HTTP header.

Then figure out how to set it with http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.set

Oops, the example includes your answer ;)

Simply check the file ending, if it's `.js`, set the appropriate MIME type to make browsers happy.

EDIT: In case this is pure node, without express, look here: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value

Comment: OK, the only piece missing is for you to figure out the MIME type of scripts, which you pop into the correct header for each response.

Answer (score 6):

`mime.lookup()` is now renamed to `mime.getType()`.
So you can do like this:

```
res.set('Content-Type', mime.getType('path/file'));
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime

Comment: what is `mime`? is that a library? what?

Comment: it's a `npm` module. so add `mime` into `package.json` and then add the following to the top of the file: `var mime = require('mime');`

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the following JSON, [containing a comprehensive list of mime types](https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list),

```
{".x3d":"application/vnd.hzn-3d-crossword",".3gp":"video/3gpp",".3g2":"video/3gpp2",".mseq":"application/vnd.mseq",".pwn":"application/vnd.3m.post-it-notes",".plb":"application/vnd.3gpp.pic-bw-large",".psb":"application/vnd.3gpp.pic-bw-small",".pvb":"application/vnd.3gpp.pic-bw-var",".tcap":"application/vnd.3gpp2.tcap",".7z":"application/x-7z-compressed",".abw":"application/x-abiword",".ace":"application/x-ace-compressed",".acc":"application/vnd.americandynamics.acc",".acu":"application/vnd.acucobol",".atc":"application/vnd.acucorp",".adp":"audio/adpcm",".aab":"application/x-authorware-bin",".aam":"application/x-authorware-map",".aas":"application/x-authorware-seg",".air":"application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip",".swf":"application/x-shockwave-flash",".fxp":"application/vnd.adobe.fxp",".pdf":"application/pdf",".ppd":"application/vnd.cups-ppd",".dir":"application/x-director",".xdp":"application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml",".xfdf":"application/vnd.adobe.xfdf",".aac":"audio/x-aac",".ahead":"application/vnd.ahead.space",".azf":"application/vnd.airzip.filesecure.azf",".azs":"application/vnd.airzip.filesecure.azs",".azw":"application/vnd.amazon.ebook",".ami":"application/vnd.amiga.ami","N/A":"application/andrew-inset",".apk":"application/vnd.android.package-archive",".cii":"application/vnd.anser-web-certificate-issue-initiation",".fti":"application/vnd.anser-web-funds-transfer-initiation",".atx":"application/vnd.antix.game-component",".dmg":"application/x-apple-diskimage",".mpkg":"application/vnd.apple.installer+xml",".aw":"application/applixware",".les":"application/vnd.hhe.lesson-player",".swi":"application/vnd.aristanetworks.swi",".s":"text/x-asm",".atomcat":"application/atomcat+xml",".atomsvc":"application/atomsvc+xml",".ac":"application/pkix-attr-cert",".aif":"audio/x-aiff",".avi":"video/x-msvideo",".aep":"application/vnd.audiograph",".dxf":"image/vnd.dxf",".dwf":"model/vnd.dwf",".par":"text/plain-bas",".bcpio":"application/x-bcpio",".bin":"application/octet-stream",".bmp":"image/bmp",".torrent":"application/x-bittorrent",".cod":"application/vnd.rim.cod",".mpm":"application/vnd.blueice.multipass",".bmi":"application/vnd.bmi",".sh":"application/x-sh",".btif":"image/prs.btif",".rep":"application/vnd.businessobjects",".bz":"application/x-bzip",".bz2":"application/x-bzip2",".csh":"application/x-csh",".c":"text/x-c",".cdxml":"application/vnd.chemdraw+xml",".css":"text/css",".cdx":"chemical/x-cdx",".cml":"chemical/x-cml",".csml":"chemical/x-csml",".cdbcmsg":"application/vnd.contact.cmsg",".cla":"application/vnd.claymore",".c4g":"application/vnd.clonk.c4group",".sub":"image/vnd.dvb.subtitle",".cdmia":"application/cdmi-capability",".cdmic":"application/cdmi-container",".cdmid":"application/cdmi-domain",".cdmio":"application/cdmi-object",".cdmiq":"application/cdmi-queue",".c11amc":"application/vnd.cluetrust.cartomobile-config",".c11amz":"application/vnd.cluetrust.cartomobile-config-pkg",".ras":"image/x-cmu-raster",".dae":"model/vnd.collada+xml",".csv":"text/csv",".cpt":"application/mac-compactpro",".wmlc":"application/vnd.wap.wmlc",".cgm":"image/cgm",".ice":"x-conference/x-cooltalk",".cmx":"image/x-cmx",".xar":"application/vnd.xara",".cmc":"application/vnd.cosmocaller",".cpio":"application/x-cpio",".clkx":"application/vnd.crick.clicker",".clkk":"application/vnd.crick.clicker.keyboard",".clkp":"application/vnd.crick.clicker.palette",".clkt":"application/vnd.crick.clicker.template",".clkw":"application/vnd.crick.clicker.wordbank",".wbs":"application/vnd.criticaltools.wbs+xml",".cryptonote":"application/vnd.rig.cryptonote",".cif":"chemical/x-cif",".cmdf":"chemical/x-cmdf",".cu":"application/cu-seeme",".cww":"application/prs.cww",".curl":"text/vnd.curl",".dcurl":"text/vnd.curl.dcurl",".mcurl":"text/vnd.curl.mcurl",".scurl":"text/vnd.curl.scurl",".car":"application/vnd.curl.car",".pcurl":"application/vnd.curl.pcurl",".cmp":"application/vnd.yellowriver-custom-menu",".dssc":"application/dssc+der",".xdssc":"application/dssc+xml",".deb":"application/x-debian-package",".uva":"audio/vnd.dece.audio",".uvi":"image/vnd.dece.graphic",".uvh":"video/vnd.dece.hd",".uvm":"video/vnd.dece.mobile",".uvu":"video/vnd.uvvu.mp4",".uvp":"video/vnd.dece.pd",".uvs":"video/vnd.dece.sd",".uvv":"video/vnd.dece.video",".dvi":"application/x-dvi",".seed":"application/vnd.fdsn.seed",".dtb":"application/x-dtbook+xml",".res":"application/x-dtbresource+xml",".ait":"application/vnd.dvb.ait",".svc":"application/vnd.dvb.service",".eol":"audio/vnd.digital-winds",".djvu":"image/vnd.djvu",".dtd":"application/xml-dtd",".mlp":"application/vnd.dolby.mlp",".wad":"application/x-doom",".dpg":"application/vnd.dpgraph",".dra":"audio/vnd.dra",".dfac":"application/vnd.dreamfactory",".dts":"audio/vnd.dts",".dtshd":"audio/vnd.dts.hd",".dwg":"image/vnd.dwg",".geo":"application/vnd.dynageo",".es":"application/ecmascript",".mag":"application/vnd.ecowin.chart",".mmr":"image/vnd.fujixerox.edmics-mmr",".rlc":"image/vnd.fujixerox.edmics-rlc",".exi":"application/exi",".mgz":"application/vnd.proteus.magazine",".epub":"application/epub+zip",".eml":"message/rfc822",".nml":"application/vnd.enliven",".xpr":"application/vnd.is-xpr",".xif":"image/vnd.xiff",".xfdl":"application/vnd.xfdl",".emma":"application/emma+xml",".ez2":"application/vnd.ezpix-album",".ez3":"application/vnd.ezpix-package",".fst":"image/vnd.fst",".fvt":"video/vnd.fvt",".fbs":"image/vnd.fastbidsheet",".fe_launch":"application/vnd.denovo.fcselayout-link",".f4v":"video/x-f4v",".flv":"video/x-flv",".fpx":"image/vnd.fpx",".npx":"image/vnd.net-fpx",".flx":"text/vnd.fmi.flexstor",".fli":"video/x-fli",".ftc":"application/vnd.fluxtime.clip",".fdf":"application/vnd.fdf",".f":"text/x-fortran",".mif":"application/vnd.mif",".fm":"application/vnd.framemaker",".fh":"image/x-freehand",".fsc":"application/vnd.fsc.weblaunch",".fnc":"application/vnd.frogans.fnc",".ltf":"application/vnd.frogans.ltf",".ddd":"application/vnd.fujixerox.ddd",".xdw":"application/vnd.fujixerox.docuworks",".xbd":"application/vnd.fujixerox.docuworks.binder",".oas":"application/vnd.fujitsu.oasys",".oa2":"application/vnd.fujitsu.oasys2",".oa3":"application/vnd.fujitsu.oasys3",".fg5":"application/vnd.fujitsu.oasysgp",".bh2":"application/vnd.fujitsu.oasysprs",".spl":"application/x-futuresplash",".fzs":"application/vnd.fuzzysheet",".g3":"image/g3fax",".gmx":"application/vnd.gmx",".gtw":"model/vnd.gtw",".txd":"application/vnd.genomatix.tuxedo",".ggb":"application/vnd.geogebra.file",".ggt":"application/vnd.geogebra.tool",".gdl":"model/vnd.gdl",".gex":"application/vnd.geometry-explorer",".gxt":"application/vnd.geonext",".g2w":"application/vnd.geoplan",".g3w":"application/vnd.geospace",".gsf":"application/x-font-ghostscript",".bdf":"application/x-font-bdf",".gtar":"application/x-gtar",".texinfo":"application/x-texinfo",".gnumeric":"application/x-gnumeric",".kml":"application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml",".kmz":"application/vnd.google-earth.kmz",".gqf":"application/vnd.grafeq",".gif":"image/gif",".gv":"text/vnd.graphviz",".gac":"application/vnd.groove-account",".ghf":"application/vnd.groove-help",".gim":"application/vnd.groove-identity-message",".grv":"application/vnd.groove-injector",".gtm":"application/vnd.groove-tool-message",".tpl":"application/vnd.groove-tool-template",".vcg":"application/vnd.groove-vcard",".h261":"video/h261",".h263":"video/h263",".h264":"video/h264",".hpid":"application/vnd.hp-hpid",".hps":"application/vnd.hp-hps",".hdf":"application/x-hdf",".rip":"audio/vnd.rip",".hbci":"application/vnd.hbci",".jlt":"application/vnd.hp-jlyt",".pcl":"application/vnd.hp-pcl",".hpgl":"application/vnd.hp-hpgl",".hvs":"application/vnd.yamaha.hv-script",".hvd":"application/vnd.yamaha.hv-dic",".hvp":"application/vnd.yamaha.hv-voice",".sfd-hdstx":"application/vnd.hydrostatix.sof-data",".stk":"application/hyperstudio",".hal":"application/vnd.hal+xml",".html":"text/html",".irm":"application/vnd.ibm.rights-management",".sc":"application/vnd.ibm.secure-container",".ics":"text/calendar",".icc":"application/vnd.iccprofile",".ico":"image/x-icon",".igl":"application/vnd.igloader",".ief":"image/ief",".ivp":"application/vnd.immervision-ivp",".ivu":"application/vnd.immervision-ivu",".rif":"application/reginfo+xml",".3dml":"text/vnd.in3d.3dml",".spot":"text/vnd.in3d.spot",".igs":"model/iges",".i2g":"application/vnd.intergeo",".cdy":"application/vnd.cinderella",".xpw":"application/vnd.intercon.formnet",".fcs":"application/vnd.isac.fcs",".ipfix":"application/ipfix",".cer":"application/pkix-cert",".pki":"application/pkixcmp",".crl":"application/pkix-crl",".pkipath":"application/pkix-pkipath",".igm":"application/vnd.insors.igm",".rcprofile":"application/vnd.ipunplugged.rcprofile",".irp":"application/vnd.irepository.package+xml",".jad":"text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor",".jar":"application/java-archive",".class":"application/java-vm",".jnlp":"application/x-java-jnlp-file",".ser":"application/java-serialized-object",".java":"text/x-java-source,java",".js":"application/javascript",".json":"application/json",".joda":"application/vnd.joost.joda-archive",".jpm":"video/jpm",".pjpeg":"image/pjpeg",".jpgv":"video/jpeg",".ktz":"application/vnd.kahootz",".mmd":"application/vnd.chipnuts.karaoke-mmd",".karbon":"application/vnd.kde.karbon",".chrt":"application/vnd.kde.kchart",".kfo":"application/vnd.kde.kformula",".flw":"application/vnd.kde.kivio",".kon":"application/vnd.kde.kontour",".kpr":"application/vnd.kde.kpresenter",".ksp":"application/vnd.kde.kspread",".kwd":"application/vnd.kde.kword",".htke":"application/vnd.kenameaapp",".kia":"application/vnd.kidspiration",".kne":"application/vnd.kinar",".sse":"application/vnd.kodak-descriptor",".lasxml":"application/vnd.las.las+xml",".latex":"application/x-latex",".lbd":"application/vnd.llamagraphics.life-balance.desktop",".lbe":"application/vnd.llamagraphics.life-balance.exchange+xml",".jam":"application/vnd.jam",".123":"application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3",".apr":"application/vnd.lotus-approach",".pre":"application/vnd.lotus-freelance",".nsf":"application/vnd.lotus-notes",".org":"application/vnd.lotus-organizer",".scm":"application/vnd.lotus-screencam",".lwp":"application/vnd.lotus-wordpro",".lvp":"audio/vnd.lucent.voice",".m3u":"audio/x-mpegurl",".m4v":"video/x-m4v",".hqx":"application/mac-binhex40",".portpkg":"application/vnd.macports.portpkg",".mgp":"application/vnd.osgeo.mapguide.package",".mrc":"application/marc",".mrcx":"application/marcxml+xml",".mxf":"application/mxf",".nbp":"application/vnd.wolfram.player",".ma":"application/mathematica",".mathml":"application/mathml+xml",".mbox":"application/mbox",".mc1":"application/vnd.medcalcdata",".mscml":"application/mediaservercontrol+xml",".cdkey":"application/vnd.mediastation.cdkey",".mwf":"application/vnd.mfer",".mfm":"application/vnd.mfmp",".msh":"model/mesh",".mads":"application/mads+xml",".mets":"application/mets+xml",".mods":"application/mods+xml",".meta4":"application/metalink4+xml",".mcd":"application/vnd.mcd",".flo":"application/vnd.micrografx.flo",".igx":"application/vnd.micrografx.igx",".es3":"application/vnd.eszigno3+xml",".mdb":"application/x-msaccess",".asf":"video/x-ms-asf",".exe":"application/x-msdownload",".cil":"application/vnd.ms-artgalry",".cab":"application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed",".ims":"application/vnd.ms-ims",".application":"application/x-ms-application",".clp":"application/x-msclip",".mdi":"image/vnd.ms-modi",".eot":"application/vnd.ms-fontobject",".xls":"application/vnd.ms-excel",".xlam":"application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroenabled.12",".xlsb":"application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroenabled.12",".xltm":"application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroenabled.12",".xlsm":"application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12",".chm":"application/vnd.ms-htmlhelp",".crd":"application/x-mscardfile",".lrm":"application/vnd.ms-lrm",".mvb":"application/x-msmediaview",".mny":"application/x-msmoney",".pptx":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",".sldx":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide",".ppsx":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow",".potx":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template",".xlsx":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",".xltx":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template",".docx":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",".dotx":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template",".obd":"application/x-msbinder",".thmx":"application/vnd.ms-officetheme",".onetoc":"application/onenote",".pya":"audio/vnd.ms-playready.media.pya",".pyv":"video/vnd.ms-playready.media.pyv",".ppt":"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",".ppam":"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroenabled.12",".sldm":"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroenabled.12",".pptm":"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroenabled.12",".ppsm":"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroenabled.12",".potm":"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroenabled.12",".mpp":"application/vnd.ms-project",".pub":"application/x-mspublisher",".scd":"application/x-msschedule",".xap":"application/x-silverlight-app",".stl":"application/vnd.ms-pki.stl",".cat":"application/vnd.ms-pki.seccat",".vsd":"application/vnd.visio",".vsdx":"application/vnd.visio2013",".wm":"video/x-ms-wm",".wma":"audio/x-ms-wma",".wax":"audio/x-ms-wax",".wmx":"video/x-ms-wmx",".wmd":"application/x-ms-wmd",".wpl":"application/vnd.ms-wpl",".wmz":"application/x-ms-wmz",".wmv":"video/x-ms-wmv",".wvx":"video/x-ms-wvx",".wmf":"application/x-msmetafile",".trm":"application/x-msterminal",".doc":"application/msword",".docm":"application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12",".dotm":"application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroenabled.12",".wri":"application/x-mswrite",".wps":"application/vnd.ms-works",".xbap":"application/x-ms-xbap",".xps":"application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument",".mid":"audio/midi",".mpy":"application/vnd.ibm.minipay",".afp":"application/vnd.ibm.modcap",".rms":"application/vnd.jcp.javame.midlet-rms",".tmo":"application/vnd.tmobile-livetv",".prc":"application/x-mobipocket-ebook",".mbk":"application/vnd.mobius.mbk",".dis":"application/vnd.mobius.dis",".plc":"application/vnd.mobius.plc",".mqy":"application/vnd.mobius.mqy",".msl":"application/vnd.mobius.msl",".txf":"application/vnd.mobius.txf",".daf":"application/vnd.mobius.daf",".fly":"text/vnd.fly",".mpc":"application/vnd.mophun.certificate",".mpn":"application/vnd.mophun.application",".mj2":"video/mj2",".mpga":"audio/mpeg",".mxu":"video/vnd.mpegurl",".mpeg":"video/mpeg",".m21":"application/mp21",".mp4a":"audio/mp4",".mp4":"application/mp4",".m3u8":"application/vnd.apple.mpegurl",".mus":"application/vnd.musician",".msty":"application/vnd.muvee.style",".mxml":"application/xv+xml",".ngdat":"application/vnd.nokia.n-gage.data",".n-gage":"application/vnd.nokia.n-gage.symbian.install",".ncx":"application/x-dtbncx+xml",".nc":"application/x-netcdf",".nlu":"application/vnd.neurolanguage.nlu",".dna":"application/vnd.dna",".nnd":"application/vnd.noblenet-directory",".nns":"application/vnd.noblenet-sealer",".nnw":"application/vnd.noblenet-web",".rpst":"application/vnd.nokia.radio-preset",".rpss":"application/vnd.nokia.radio-presets",".n3":"text/n3",".edm":"application/vnd.novadigm.edm",".edx":"application/vnd.novadigm.edx",".ext":"application/vnd.novadigm.ext",".gph":"application/vnd.flographit",".ecelp4800":"audio/vnd.nuera.ecelp4800",".ecelp7470":"audio/vnd.nuera.ecelp7470",".ecelp9600":"audio/vnd.nuera.ecelp9600",".oda":"application/oda",".ogx":"application/ogg",".oga":"audio/ogg",".ogv":"video/ogg",".dd2":"application/vnd.oma.dd2+xml",".oth":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web",".opf":"application/oebps-package+xml",".qbo":"application/vnd.intu.qbo",".oxt":"application/vnd.openofficeorg.extension",".osf":"application/vnd.yamaha.openscoreformat",".weba":"audio/webm",".webm":"video/webm",".odc":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart",".otc":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart-template",".odb":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database",".odf":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula",".odft":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template",".odg":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics",".otg":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template",".odi":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image",".oti":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image-template",".odp":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",".otp":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template",".ods":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",".ots":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template",".odt":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",".odm":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master",".ott":"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template",".ktx":"image/ktx",".sxc":"application/vnd.sun.xml.calc",".stc":"application/vnd.sun.xml.calc.template",".sxd":"application/vnd.sun.xml.draw",".std":"application/vnd.sun.xml.draw.template",".sxi":"application/vnd.sun.xml.impress",".sti":"application/vnd.sun.xml.impress.template",".sxm":"application/vnd.sun.xml.math",".sxw":"application/vnd.sun.xml.writer",".sxg":"application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.global",".stw":"application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.template",".otf":"application/x-font-otf",".osfpvg":"application/vnd.yamaha.openscoreformat.osfpvg+xml",".dp":"application/vnd.osgi.dp",".pdb":"application/vnd.palm",".p":"text/x-pascal",".paw":"application/vnd.pawaafile",".pclxl":"application/vnd.hp-pclxl",".efif":"application/vnd.picsel",".pcx":"image/x-pcx",".psd":"image/vnd.adobe.photoshop",".prf":"application/pics-rules",".pic":"image/x-pict",".chat":"application/x-chat",".p10":"application/pkcs10",".p12":"application/x-pkcs12",".p7m":"application/pkcs7-mime",".p7s":"application/pkcs7-signature",".p7r":"application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp",".p7b":"application/x-pkcs7-certificates",".p8":"application/pkcs8",".plf":"application/vnd.pocketlearn",".pnm":"image/x-portable-anymap",".pbm":"image/x-portable-bitmap",".pcf":"application/x-font-pcf",".pfr":"application/font-tdpfr",".pgn":"application/x-chess-pgn",".pgm":"image/x-portable-graymap",".png":"image/x-png",".ppm":"image/x-portable-pixmap",".pskcxml":"application/pskc+xml",".pml":"application/vnd.ctc-posml",".ai":"application/postscript",".pfa":"application/x-font-type1",".pbd":"application/vnd.powerbuilder6",".pgp":"application/pgp-signature",".box":"application/vnd.previewsystems.box",".ptid":"application/vnd.pvi.ptid1",".pls":"application/pls+xml",".str":"application/vnd.pg.format",".ei6":"application/vnd.pg.osasli",".dsc":"text/prs.lines.tag",".psf":"application/x-font-linux-psf",".qps":"application/vnd.publishare-delta-tree",".wg":"application/vnd.pmi.widget",".qxd":"application/vnd.quark.quarkxpress",".esf":"application/vnd.epson.esf",".msf":"application/vnd.epson.msf",".ssf":"application/vnd.epson.ssf",".qam":"application/vnd.epson.quickanime",".qfx":"application/vnd.intu.qfx",".qt":"video/quicktime",".rar":"application/x-rar-compressed",".ram":"audio/x-pn-realaudio",".rmp":"audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin",".rsd":"application/rsd+xml",".rm":"application/vnd.rn-realmedia",".bed":"application/vnd.realvnc.bed",".mxl":"application/vnd.recordare.musicxml",".musicxml":"application/vnd.recordare.musicxml+xml",".rnc":"application/relax-ng-compact-syntax",".rdz":"application/vnd.data-vision.rdz",".rdf":"application/rdf+xml",".rp9":"application/vnd.cloanto.rp9",".jisp":"application/vnd.jisp",".rtf":"application/rtf",".rtx":"text/richtext",".link66":"application/vnd.route66.link66+xml",".shf":"application/shf+xml",".st":"application/vnd.sailingtracker.track",".svg":"image/svg+xml",".sus":"application/vnd.sus-calendar",".sru":"application/sru+xml",".setpay":"application/set-payment-initiation",".setreg":"application/set-registration-initiation",".sema":"application/vnd.sema",".semd":"application/vnd.semd",".semf":"application/vnd.semf",".see":"application/vnd.seemail",".snf":"application/x-font-snf",".spq":"application/scvp-vp-request",".spp":"application/scvp-vp-response",".scq":"application/scvp-cv-request",".scs":"application/scvp-cv-response",".sdp":"application/sdp",".etx":"text/x-setext",".movie":"video/x-sgi-movie",".ifm":"application/vnd.shana.informed.formdata",".itp":"application/vnd.shana.informed.formtemplate",".iif":"application/vnd.shana.informed.interchange",".ipk":"application/vnd.shana.informed.package",".tfi":"application/thraud+xml",".shar":"application/x-shar",".rgb":"image/x-rgb",".slt":"application/vnd.epson.salt",".aso":"application/vnd.accpac.simply.aso",".imp":"application/vnd.accpac.simply.imp",".twd":"application/vnd.simtech-mindmapper",".csp":"application/vnd.commonspace",".saf":"application/vnd.yamaha.smaf-audio",".mmf":"application/vnd.smaf",".spf":"application/vnd.yamaha.smaf-phrase",".teacher":"application/vnd.smart.teacher",".svd":"application/vnd.svd",".rq":"application/sparql-query",".srx":"application/sparql-results+xml",".gram":"application/srgs",".grxml":"application/srgs+xml",".ssml":"application/ssml+xml",".skp":"application/vnd.koan",".sgml":"text/sgml",".sdc":"application/vnd.stardivision.calc",".sda":"application/vnd.stardivision.draw",".sdd":"application/vnd.stardivision.impress",".smf":"application/vnd.stardivision.math",".sdw":"application/vnd.stardivision.writer",".sgl":"application/vnd.stardivision.writer-global",".sm":"application/vnd.stepmania.stepchart",".sit":"application/x-stuffit",".sitx":"application/x-stuffitx",".sdkm":"application/vnd.solent.sdkm+xml",".xo":"application/vnd.olpc-sugar",".au":"audio/basic",".wqd":"application/vnd.wqd",".sis":"application/vnd.symbian.install",".smi":"application/smil+xml",".xsm":"application/vnd.syncml+xml",".bdm":"application/vnd.syncml.dm+wbxml",".xdm":"application/vnd.syncml.dm+xml",".sv4cpio":"application/x-sv4cpio",".sv4crc":"application/x-sv4crc",".sbml":"application/sbml+xml",".tsv":"text/tab-separated-values",".tiff":"image/tiff",".tao":"application/vnd.tao.intent-module-archive",".tar":"application/x-tar",".tcl":"application/x-tcl",".tex":"application/x-tex",".tfm":"application/x-tex-tfm",".tei":"application/tei+xml",".txt":"text/plain",".dxp":"application/vnd.spotfire.dxp",".sfs":"application/vnd.spotfire.sfs",".tsd":"application/timestamped-data",".tpt":"application/vnd.trid.tpt",".mxs":"application/vnd.triscape.mxs",".t":"text/troff",".tra":"application/vnd.trueapp",".ttf":"application/x-font-ttf",".ttl":"text/turtle",".umj":"application/vnd.umajin",".uoml":"application/vnd.uoml+xml",".unityweb":"application/vnd.unity",".ufd":"application/vnd.ufdl",".uri":"text/uri-list",".utz":"application/vnd.uiq.theme",".ustar":"application/x-ustar",".uu":"text/x-uuencode",".vcs":"text/x-vcalendar",".vcf":"text/x-vcard",".vcd":"application/x-cdlink",".vsf":"application/vnd.vsf",".wrl":"model/vrml",".vcx":"application/vnd.vcx",".mts":"model/vnd.mts",".vtu":"model/vnd.vtu",".vis":"application/vnd.visionary",".viv":"video/vnd.vivo",".ccxml":"application/ccxml+xml,",".vxml":"application/voicexml+xml",".src":"application/x-wais-source",".wbxml":"application/vnd.wap.wbxml",".wbmp":"image/vnd.wap.wbmp",".wav":"audio/x-wav",".davmount":"application/davmount+xml",".woff":"application/x-font-woff",".wspolicy":"application/wspolicy+xml",".webp":"image/webp",".wtb":"application/vnd.webturbo",".wgt":"application/widget",".hlp":"application/winhlp",".wml":"text/vnd.wap.wml",".wmls":"text/vnd.wap.wmlscript",".wmlsc":"application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc",".wpd":"application/vnd.wordperfect",".stf":"application/vnd.wt.stf",".wsdl":"application/wsdl+xml",".xbm":"image/x-xbitmap",".xpm":"image/x-xpixmap",".xwd":"image/x-xwindowdump",".der":"application/x-x509-ca-cert",".fig":"application/x-xfig",".xhtml":"application/xhtml+xml",".xml":"application/rss+xml",".xdf":"application/xcap-diff+xml",".xenc":"application/xenc+xml",".xer":"application/patch-ops-error+xml",".rl":"application/resource-lists+xml",".rs":"application/rls-services+xml",".rld":"application/resource-lists-diff+xml",".xslt":"application/xslt+xml",".xop":"application/xop+xml",".xpi":"application/x-xpinstall",".xspf":"application/xspf+xml",".xul":"application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml",".xyz":"chemical/x-xyz",".yaml":"text/yaml",".yang":"application/yang",".yin":"application/yin+xml",".zir":"application/vnd.zul",".zip":"application/zip",".zmm":"application/vnd.handheld-entertainment+xml",".zaz":"application/vnd.zzazz.deck+xml",".atom":"application/atom+xml",".jpeg":"image/jpeg",".jpg":"image/jpeg",".rss":"application/rss+xml"}
```

to a file on your server called `mimeTypes.json` (for example), read it with `var mimes = require("mimeTypes.json")`, then before res.end simply do

```
var extension = req.url.substring(
    req.
    url.lastIndexOf(".")
);

var type = mimes[extension];
if(type) {
    res.setHeader("content-type", type);
}
```

P.S.

The JSON was parsed from the JavaScript console from the link above. In case of changes, simply run the following in your console at that page to get the new JSON:

```
var j = 
Array.apply(
    null,
    document
    .getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows
).map(x => [
    x.cells[2].innerText,
    x.cells[1].innerText
]).slice(1)
.filter(x=>
    !x[1].includes("x-citrix-jpeg")
)

j.forEach(x => {
    x[0].indexOf(",") > -1 && (
        x[0].split(",").forEach(y =>
             j.push([y.trim(), x[1]])
        )
    )
})

j = Object.fromEntries(
    j.filter(x=>
        x[0].indexOf(",") === -1
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had problems using your handler function because convertURL and okURL functions where not defined. I modified the code a little and finished looking like this

```
function handler(req, res) 
{
    // /home/juan/Documentos/push-api-demo is the path of the root directory of the server
    var url             = '/home/juan/Documentos/push-api-demo' + req.url;
    var file_exists     = fs.existsSync(url);

    if (file_exists) 
    {
        fs.readFile(url, function(err, data) 
        {
            if (err) 
            {
                res.writeHead(404);
                return res.end("File not found.");
            }

            res.setHeader("Content-Type", mime.lookup(url)); 
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(data);
        });
    } 
    else 
    {
        res.writeHead(403);
        return res.end("Forbidden.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will generate a minimal [{mime, exts}, ...] array from :

https://github.com/patrickmccallum/mimetype-io/

```
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/patrickmccallum/mimetype-io/master/src/mimeData.json")
.then(
    res => 
        res
        .json()
)
.then(
    mimeTypes => 
        mimeTypes
        .map(
            mime => ({
                mime: mime.name, 
                exts: mime.fileTypes
            })
        )
)
.then(
    cleanTypes => {
            
        // console.log(cleanTypes);
        // write JSON.stringify(cleanTypes) to file system
        // ...
            
    }
);
```

Then find any mimeType from file extension using :

```
let ext = ".flac";
    
let mimeType = (cleanTypes.find(mime => mime.exts.includes(ext)) || {mime: "application/octet-stream"}).mime;
    
console.log(ext, ">", mimeType);
```

Defaults to "application/octet-stream" if not found.