# How do i fix MIME type error? ubuntu vs windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express, ubuntu

I have an application which I've built on my laptop booted in too windows 10. The problem is when I boot into ubuntu and start the server with nodemon and check the website in chrome I get this error and the scripts won't run.

**"Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.".**

The thing is it works when I'm running chrome on windows but not chrome on ubuntu.

The project is made with node and express. Heres the code to serve the files.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000'));
```

my index.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  <script type="module" src="./js/index.js" defer></script>
  <title>Mina Kontakter</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

I really have no clue what to do. I find it really weird that it works when I boot into windows but not ubuntu.

Comment: Show the error and the exact request that's showing that error.

Comment: The error is in the original question? I happens when i try to go to localhost:3000 in chrome on ubuntu. But on windows everything is working as it should.

Comment: Could be related to the expected a response header issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971918/how-do-i-set-a-mime-type-before-sending-a-file-in-node-js)

Comment: I just fixed it! The problem was that one of the files began with a lowercase letter instead of an uppcased one.