# Integrating Frontend Javascript with Backend Node.Js and mySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have tried searching around, but could not really find a solution to my question. Either that or I am not really understanding something properly.

I have a page with a simple form that uses Javascript to alert the user of their inputs upon clicking the submit button. I've also created a Node.Js function to insert input into a mySQL database. What I am unsure of is if I am able to link the above together without using a framework like Express Js.

My codes as follows:

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>homework</title>
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="../js/form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This is a header</h1>
    <div class="card input-form">
      <p>Enter your details below.</p>
      <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
      <input id="inputFirstName" type="text" name="inputFirstName" required /><br><br>
      <label for="inputLastName">Last Name</label>
      <input id="inputLastName" type="text" name="inputLastName" required /><br><br>
      <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="submitDetails();">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

form.js

```
let firstName, lastName, response;

function submitDetails() {
  firstName = document.getElementById("inputFirstName").value;
  lastName = document.getElementById("inputLastName").value;

  response = confirm(`Please verify the submitted details.

First Name: ${firstName}
Last Name: ${lastName}`);

  if (response == true) {
    alert("Personal details submitted.");
  } else {
    alert("You have cancelled your submission.");
  }
}
```

app.js

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const config = require("./config.js");
// console.log(config);
const connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("Connected to mySQL Database");
  } else {
    console.log("Connection Failed");
  }
});

const newTable = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS details (
                  id int primary key auto_increment,
                  firstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                  lastName varchar(50) NOT NULL
                )`;

connection.query(newTable, function (err, results, fields) {
  // console.log(results);
});

module.exports = connection;

let firstName, lastName;

function insertEntry(firstName, lastName) {
  firstName = "John";
  lastName = "Doe";

  let newEntry = `INSERT INTO details (firstName, lastName)
                  VALUES ('${firstName}', '${lastName}')`;

  connection.query(newEntry, function (err, results, fields) {
    // console.log(results);
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Entry inserted into table");
    }
  });
}

insertEntry();

connection.end(function () {
  console.log("Connection Terminated");
});
```

config.js

```
let config = {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "test",
  password: "password",
  database: "homework",
};

module.exports = config;
```

My Folder Tree is as such:

```
homework
|--views
| |--index.php
|
|--js
| |--app.js
| |--config.js
| |--form.js
|
|--css
  |--style.css
```

======================================================

Update using Fedex7501's answer:

app.js

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method === "POST") {
      let body = "";
      req.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body += chunk.toString();
      });
      req.on("end", () => {
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        insertEntry(body.firstName, body.lastName);

        // res.end("ok");
      });
      // } else {
      //   res.end();
    }
    fs.readFile("../views/index.php", function (err, data) {
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      res.write(data);
      return res.end();
    });
  })
  .listen(8000);

const mysql = require("mysql");
const config = require("./config.js");

const connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("Connected to mySQL Database");
  } else {
    console.log("Connection Failed");
  }
});

const newTable = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS details (
                    id int primary key auto_increment,
                    firstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                    lastName varchar(50) NOT NULL
                  )`;

connection.query(newTable, function (err, results, fields) {
  // console.log(results);
});

let firstName, lastName;

function insertEntry(firstName, lastName) {
  // firstName = "John";
  // lastName = "Doe";

  let newEntry = `INSERT INTO details (firstName, lastName)
                  VALUES ('${firstName}', '${lastName}')`;

  connection.query(newEntry, function (err, results, fields) {
    // console.log(results);
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Entry inserted into table");
    }
  });
}

// insertEntry();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the http module on the server like this:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        //Notice we aren't handling routes here

        let body = '';
        req.on('data', chunk => {
            body += chunk.toString();
        });
        req.on('end', () => {
            //Finished receiving data

            body = JSON.parse(body)
            insertEntry(body.firstName, body.lastName)

            res.end('ok');
        });
    }
    else {
        if (req.url === '/'){
            //Serve index file
            fs.readFile("../views/index.php", function (err, data) {
                res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
                res.write(data);
                return res.end();
            });
        } else {
            //Serve static content
            
            //This is dangerous because it allows reading any file like app.js
            //Note: remove the .. in the src and href in the php file, it looks cleaner this way
            fs.readFile('../' + req.url, (err, data) => {
                if (err){
                    res.statusCode = 404;
                    res.end('File not found');
                } else {
                    //Here we should parse the file name to determine the content type
                    //I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader
                    //Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11972512/8891434

                    //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript')
                    
                    res.end(data)
                }
            })
        }
        res.end();
    }
});

server.listen(80);
```

And on the client I prefer to use the axios library

Add this inside the <head> to import it

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

And then you can send the data like this:

```
let firstName, lastName, response;

function submitDetails() {
  firstName = document.getElementById("inputFirstName").value;
  lastName = document.getElementById("inputLastName").value;

  response = confirm(`Please verify the submitted details.

  First Name: ${firstName}
  Last Name: ${lastName}`);

  if (response == true) {
    //Send data
    axios.post('your_backend_ip', {firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName}).then(() => {
       alert("Personal details submitted.");
    })
  } else {
    alert("You have cancelled your submission.");
  }
}
```

Of course, this is a very simple example since we don't handle multiple routes. I would recommend learning how to use the Express framework, it's easy to use and much more powerful than the http module.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I have managed to implement it, but there are a couple of issues that I am still facing which I am unsure why they are happening. It would be great if you could help shed some light on it. I do not know if there's a better way to present my queries, so I've added them as separate comments below. Do let me know if there's a better alternative. I have also included my edited code in the main post. Appreciate the assistance!

Comment: 1. To call my `index.php` page, I used the File Server module with a .readFile method. However, when I am in the homework directory and running app.js through `node ./js/app.js`, I get a `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received u
ndefined`. If I am in the js folder and run `node app.js`, it works.

Comment: 2. I realised that if I put the `fs.readFile` method (without a `res.end`) ahead of the if-else statement, the page does not load. But when the if-else statement (without any `res.end` statements) is ahead of the `fs.readFile` method, it works.

Comment: 3. After I am able to call my `index.php` page, I realised that my `style.css` and `form.js` in the css and js folders respectively are not working. Instead, if I enclose the contents of my `form.js` in a `<script>` tag within the body of `index.php`, it works. Not sure why I cannot include the two files.

Comment: Yeah with this code you can't serve static content like css and js files because the function we are passing to http.createServer handles all requests. So no matter the route it always returns the php file for all GET requests. I'll update the answer to include some basic routing.

Comment: @Zotius about point number 2. when you put the fs.readFile before the if else the page didn't load because the readFile function is asynchronous. This means that the function continued to execute, got to the else part and ended the request. Then by the time the file loaded it tried to send the data but the request was already closed.

Comment: Thanks @Fedex7501 for the explanations. I can still do internal css and js to achieve my intent for this exercise so not much of a problem. But the snippets on basic routing helps my understanding a little more. I guess utilising a framework like Express will still be most ideal in this scenario.

Comment: One last clarification on the if-else statement for the POST request. Correct me if I am wrong, but the reason why we have the `req.on('data', chunk...` function is basically to convert whatever input is parsed to a string, there after to a JSON format using the `req.on('end', ...` function so that the variables can be used later right? What does the `chunk` portion do? I'm assuming it basically refers to any block of input? Never seen `chunk` before.

Comment: @Zotius data isn't sent to the server all at once. It's sent through many TCP packets. The chunk would be each package's data, which is just a sequence of bytes. Notice how we convert it `chunk.toString()` and append it because we know the body will be JSON text but it could be anything really